# Migrate from VSS to SVN retaining history

Tags: svn, migration, visual-sourcesafe

We are trying to use http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/ to migrate from VSS to SVN but we also want to retain the history.
We are trying to find out what pre-commit hook scripts need to be used for this, if these are readily available and can be used as-is.

Thank you.

Regards,
Rupa

Comment: possible duplicate of [VSS to SVN migration; tool suggestions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961701/vss-to-svn-migration-tool-suggestions)

Answer (score 2):

We had good experience with [VSS2SVN](https://github.com/irontoby/vss2svn/) including the history (formerly in [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/vss2svn/)). If I remember it correctly, no customization or hook modification was required. It was quite fast and reliable even with huge repository. We had to use the daily build, though. See [Performance in Subversion vs. SourceSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239452/performance-in-subversion-vs-sourcesafe/239520#239520) for further notes

Note: while the name is almost the same, the tool I am talking about is a different one from what you have linked.