# About SourceSafe licenses

Tags: .net, visual-sourcesafe

If I have license for VisualStudio 2005 and 2008

I have license for SourceSafe too ? or I need to buy it ?

From where I can get One ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

"You need a VSS license on each machine where you install VSS. If you decide to use a dedicated "server" machine to host the VSS database then yes, you need a license for that machine, too."

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/1e43c9fe-3ac1-4287-97ad-d1c93e3c140b

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a [real source code control system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073/alternatives-to-visual-sourcesafe-that-integrate-with-visual-studio).

I'm not being facetious or dismissive here. SourceSafe is better than nothing, but practically any other SCCS is better than SourceSafe -- there were reasons MS didn't use it in-house (e.g. high risk of database corruption, inefficient use of fileshares, no branching support). TFS is quite decent (an **is** dogfooded by MS), and many swear by Subversion. There are plenty other tools out there as well, many of which integrate just as well with VS.

Comment: I agree and personally recommend Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that VSS is often criticised for its shortcomings. You might want to consider another VCS, e.g. SVN or git.

See e.g.
[How do I convince my team to drop sourcesafe and move to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115493/how-do-i-convince-my-team-to-drop-sourcesafe-and-move-to-svn)

Answer (score 0):

Are you licensed via MSDN? If so, then a "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN Premium" or "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN Professional" subscription [includes licenses for VSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx).

However, I also repeat the suggestions to look at other offerings. My preference is for [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) + [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (client)