# VSS 2005 and VS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I use VS 2005 and VSS 2005. Every time I close VS I get error: ss.ini not found. But except this VSS works fine, no problems when I open VS and do check in and check out. ss.ini is present and VSS repository specified as network path. I just worry that I can have problems later.

Comment: BTW, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224537/why-is-visual-sourcesafe-viewed-so-poorly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ss.ini keeps track of your preferences, project locations, dialog settings, and such. The ss.ini needs to be in the user's folder for the data base. In my case, it is `C:\DEV_\VSS\SourceSafe\users\amissico\ss.ini`.

If the file exists, check permissions of folder and file. If the file doesn't exist, check permissions of folder.

Comment: File is there and I think that permissions are okay, because I could login to VSS without problem and open any project, problem only when I close VS.

Comment: You are getting the error because the VSS provider is trying to save your settings. Try removing the file.

Comment: okay, thanks, will try tomorrow, maybe it can't overwrite file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste SS.ini file from user folder from another user folder into user folder with whom you are getting an issue like :
Source: Project\users\ajit\SS.ini
Destination: Project\users\Sujit\SS.ini

Answer (score 0):

VSS provides Deploy command which allows you publish files to your web server. You can check the following link for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509340(v=vs.80).aspx