# IS there any way to Create a CI with Sourcesafe

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, visual-sourcesafe

I want to create a CI for my company and we are using Sourcesafe as our repository.

I want to know is there any way to create a CI Build process with Sourcesafe?

I read some CI process with TFS and GIT (svn) but can't find an article for Sourcesafe?

What should I do?

Comment: *What should I do?* You should migrate away from Visual Sourcesafe **as soon as possible**.

Comment: @Greg - Sourcesafe fit our needs and we haven't any problem with it but What do you suggest ? TFS or GIT ? I think TFS is better.

Comment: This article recommends Svn, Git, or Hg, and says to leave VSS asap: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/VersionControlTools.html

Comment: @Nasser Hajloo: You might think TFS is better, but I recommend Git, Mercurial, or Subversion (depending on your tastes).

Comment: @Nasser: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224537/why-is-visual-sourcesafe-viewed-so-poorly. Also, doesn't it bother you to rely on unsupported products? I mean, you do realize it's been version 6 for about a decade?

Comment: An updated survey of different source control systems from Martin Fowler is at http://martinfowler.com/bliki/VcsSurvey.html

Comment: I built CI using batch-files and VSS commandlines back when VSS6 was brand new. You're about 15 years overdue for a switch away from VSS. VSS is total rubbish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net) has a [VSS plugin](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#vss) also.

But seriously... VSS... in 2010...

Comment: CruiseControl works well if you are stuck on VSS.  I agree though, dump vss asap.

Comment: It's 2018 and we are still stuck with it :(

Answer (score 3):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) has [a VSS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Visual+SourceSafe+Plugin).  ([Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) [too](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Visual+SourceSafe+Plugin).)

Comment: I'm stuck on sourcesafe as well. I had an easier time getting Hudson setup and running than CruiseControl.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use TeamCity with SourceSafe.

Answer (score 1):

Our Parabuild provides [**Continuous Integration for Visual SourceSafe**](http://www.viewtier.com/products/parabuild/index.htm) out of the box. It's a fully-supported configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Source Safe is the devil's work.

I'd go Subversion + TeamCity myself.