# Which CI is suitable for .Net

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I want to Automate the build process of my company. We are Using.Net platform for developing softwares and currently using VisualSourceSafe as source control.

So I want to know that which tools is the best CI for .net Platform.

Based on my searches I found that CrouseControl.Net is better than others so What Do you think.

note: I also ask a question about : [integrating Sourcesafe with a CI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392143/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-ci-with-sourcesafe)  but that's different than this question.

TeamCity - CrouseControl.Net - or etc

Comment: Don't forget Hudson! It's free AND awesome. There are a ton of plugins, including Visual SourceNotSoSafe. That it's written in Java doesn't preclude you from building .NET projects with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration) has answers that compare cruisecontrol.net and teamcity.

Personally, I have been very happy with Teamcity. I used cc.net for years, but TeamCity has worked better for me.

A long list of continuous integration options is at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)

Comment: @Mike - thanks for question, I'm also looking for other option CC.net and TeamCity are good but is there any third option which could be used ?

Comment: @Nasser Hajiloo - yes there are several options. I have not used any of the others so I don't feel comfortable comparing them, but I will list some that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is very subjective.

If you want to get up and running quickly, TeamCity is the way forward IMO. Its dashboard UI also knocks spots off of CruiseControl.NET's user interface.

CC.NET requires quite a bit of manual XML configuration setup etc., but once setup it's quite nice, and of course is free. TeamCity is free for up to 10 developers or so.

Comment: Teamcity is free for up to 20 developers, 3 agents and 20 build configurations.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2010 ;) Integrated source control, build system, document repository, reporting, work item tracking, and best of all: build for .NET

Answer (score 0):

from [The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) book - Chapter 6

- CruiseControl.NET ([www.cruisecontrolnet.org](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/))
- TeamCity ([jetbrains.com/teamcity/](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/))
- NAnt ([nant.sourceforge.net](http://nant.sourceforge.net))
- MSBuild ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5%28VS.80%29.aspx))
- FinalBuilder ([www.FinalBuilder.com](http://www.FinalBuilder.com))
- Visual Build Pro ([www.kinook.com](http://www.kinook.com))
- Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx)

One popular continuous integration tool is **CruiseControl.NET**. It’s
**fully open source** and supports both the idea of ***tasks***, which are individual
commands that are run during a build, and the concept of ***triggers***,
which can start a build automatically when certain events occur, such
as source control updates.

Among the **commercial tools**, Visual Studio Team System 2008 supports
automated builds and continuous integration out of the box. If
that’s a bit beyond your budget, look at FinalBuilder and Visual Build
Pro. These two commercial and highly successful build tools allow
visual editing and maintenance of automated build projects. That
means easier maintenance of the build file, which can get pretty scary
for larger projects.